# Flask NameError: name 'app' is not defined

Tags: python, flask

I am new in python and use learn flask framework, I got error in some line of code

please guide me:

```
from flask import redirect
@app.route('/')
def index():
   return redirect("http://www.google.com")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "redirect.py", line 2, in <module>
    @app.route('/')
NameError: name 'app' is not defined
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line of code that you were missing that u didn't declare the "app"  correctly

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

add this before

@app.route('/')
The object initialisation has to be done first

Answer (score 2):

Within your `redirect.py` module, you did not appropriately import `app` instance into it.

```
# This app instance is what is missing from `redirect.py`
app = Flask(__name__)

# Only then can you use it as a decorator
@app.route('/')
def handler():
    pass
```

By the way, you probably didn't post all the code, but you might want to avoid naming the module `redirect.py` since it can collide with `flask.redirect`